# Android Listview and Focus item through TrackBall

Tags: android

i have listview ,with each row contain 5 button,i can move the row using tackball,but i can't focus the buttons in the row,how can i done this,please help me.

i have given my layout of the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/outer">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Billing "
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="140dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_rank_a"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <Button
                        android:background="@drawable/rank_a"
                        android:id="@+id/rank_a"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_rank_b"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rank_b"
                        android:id="@+id/rank_b"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="30dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_rank_c"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rank_c"
                        android:id="@+id/rank_c"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="30dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_rank_d"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rank_d"
                        android:id="@+id/rank_d"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="30dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/layout_rank_f"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/rank_f"
                        android:id="@+id/rank_f"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:layout_height="30dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 10 LinearLayout, try using the relative layout. It can be used to place buttons where ever you want. Read up on it on [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html). Also this should make all buttons available for the trackball.